# how to validate xml schema (XSD) with soap response (xml) in karate dsl

Tags: java, soap, xsd, xsd-validation, karate

I am using `Karate dsl framework` to automate soap request,
I want to validate the response which is in XML format with XML Schema (XSD).

I required the `SchemaUtil.java` code and functions to call it in .feature file. I tried with Rest API, karate demo for validating json schema and found correct result, but for soap (xml, xsd) not getting .I am trying with this `SchemaUtil.java` for XSD Validation.

```
public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){

        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = 
                    SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
        } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for JSON schema, try to follow the same approach for XML: [`schema.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/schema/schema.feature).

Normally in Karate you don't need to do JSON or XML schema validation, because Karate has a simpler approach. Actually when you use XML to `match` the response, this is *better* than schema validation because you are validating actual values, not just the structure of the XML.

So please try to convince whoever is asking you to do this that this is not needed.

If you insist on doing XML Schema validation, then use Java code like you are already trying to do. Get it to work without Karate first as a normal Java test or `main` method. Then you can easily integrate into Karate, refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

Otherwise, this is not really a question related to Karate.